# Sorting contours in OpenCV from an image

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, contour

I am developing a program that can detect and recognize characters. Recognition is working fine, but I have a problem when it comes to sorting contours. I have to sort them from left to right and from top to bottom to get the right words out of an image but as the contours have different heights I just can't get them in the right order. The problem lies in my sorting function.

Here is how the contours look like:

[image: The image I with contours.]

And here is my valid contours class with sorting function in it:

```
class ContourWithData {
public:

std::vector<cv::Point> ptContour;           
cv::Rect boundingRect;                      
float fltArea;                              

                                            
bool checkIfContourIsValid() {                              
    if (fltArea < MIN_CONTOUR_AREA) return false;            
    return true;                                            
}


static bool sortByBoundingRectXPosition(const ContourWithData& cwdLeft, const ContourWithData& cwdRight) {      

    if (cwdLeft.boundingRect.y == cwdRight.boundingRect.y) {
        return(cwdLeft.boundingRect.x + 1000 * cwdLeft.boundingRect.y  < cwdRight.boundingRect.x + 1000 * cwdRight.boundingRect.y);

    } else if (cwdLeft.boundingRect.height > cwdRight.boundingRect.height) {
        int sub = cwdLeft.boundingRect.height - cwdRight.boundingRect.height;

        return(cwdLeft.boundingRect.x + 1000 * cwdLeft.boundingRect.y  < cwdRight.boundingRect.x + 1000 * (cwdRight.boundingRect.y - sub));

    } else {
        int sub = cwdRight.boundingRect.height - cwdLeft.boundingRect.height;

        return(cwdLeft.boundingRect.x + 1000 * (cwdLeft.boundingRect.y - sub)  < cwdRight.boundingRect.x + 1000 * cwdRight.boundingRect.y);

    
    }
}

};
```

And this is my console output:

```
domainocmlsroudtosonsorma0rleauehacklnppjggandethirmissiontoemowerstudenthackersar0undpteworlhdyouarethenextenerati0nofudmgpancong0rathtosuccesssaswihvttdthkersyurloppgresselndomnnamereatnaikdcnaaueaihlejoarmaggg
```

Characters like p and g are put at the end..¸

Tried the mass center:

```
static bool sortByBoundingRectXPosition(const ContourWithData& cwdLeft, const ContourWithData& cwdRight) {      // this function allows us to sort

    Mat left = Mat(srcImg, cwdLeft.boundingRect);
    Mat right = Mat(srcImg, cwdRight.boundingRect);

    Point massCenterLeft = findMassCenter(left);
    Point massCenterRight = findMassCenter(right);

    return (massCenterLeft.x + massCenterLeft.y < massCenterRight.x + massCenterRight.y);
    
}
```

And the mass center function:

```
Point findMassCenter(Mat src)
{
    int totalX = 0, totalY = 0;
    int cnt = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < src.cols; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < src.rows; y++)
        {
            int val = src.at<uchar>(Point(x, y));
            if (val < 240)
            {
                totalX += x;
                totalY += y;
                cnt++;
            }
        }
    }
    return Point(totalX / cnt, totalY / cnt);
}
```

Comment: Find the center of mass for each of the contour. It will return a coordinate `(x, y)` for each contour. Sort them based on `x` followed by `y`.

Comment: dont sort them all at once. Build lines from clusters of y coordinates first

Comment: for example reduce all bounding boxes to their center of gravities and then use a ransac multi-line detection and cluster. Afaik there are "stroke width" approaches for text detection, too, which might help. Probably the task isn't trivial but does not look impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to do this was to:

1. Find the line contours (copy the original image and grayscale, threshold, dilate it) and then sort the line contours by y from top to bottom.
2. Take the rectangle from the found line and crop the same rectangle from the original image. Then find the contours in the cropped out image and single out valid ones, then sort them by x from left to right.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be the following: you are using `std::sort` algorithm to sort characters by X and then by Y, but this algorithm is not guaranteed to be stable. That is, there are some undesired swaps because Y coordinates have different ordering.

Try using `std::stable_sort` algorithm and do what Jeru Luke suggested in his comment - stable_sort by X, then stable sort by Y.

Another modification might be an attempt to first split all characters into lines (that is, collect all characters with approximately similar Y coordinates) and only then sort those character lines by X.

Comment: I have now tried to use stable_sort but the output is till not correct. FIrst I call stable_sort on X and then I make another call on Y coordinate.